# Creating Rewrite rule for url's in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp-2.3

I want to create a rewrite rule in the `.htaccess` file, for the following url's. My `.htaccess` file is in `webroot` folder and i am using `cakephp` framework.

```
 /user/images/photo.png
 /user/member/images/loader.gif
```

Here is my `.htaccess`, but it's not working, gives Missing action exception error for the above url's

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine ON
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(img|images)/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess file?

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?

Comment: Have you enabled `.htaccess` style file usage inside the http servers configuration?

Comment: Also tell what URLs are you trying in your testing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this rule is you changed default cake rule.

you should leave the default rule intact and add another `RewriteCond` and  `RewriteRule` for images.

from your question, there's no telling what should be happening with the images, which made you change the rule this way, but at least I think I gave you a good starting point.